# 1 авторизация на 2-х сайтах laravel

Tags: laravel

Идея такая:

Есть 2 сайта на laravel. При авторизации на 1 сайте, сначала идет поиск данных аккаунта в базе этого сайта, если их нет, то идем в базу 2 сайта и ищем их там. И аналогично со 2 сайтом(Сначала ищем в базе этого сайта, если нет идем в базу 1 сайта и ищем там)

По сути нужно просто подключить 2 базу от 2 сайта. Вопрос как это сделать и как в дальнейшем работать с этой бд

Сайты и базы находятся на одном сервере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что наименее костыльный способ (сколько не видел как реализуют многосайтовость  - во всех движках с этим непросто) будет на основе кастомной авторизации, в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) вопрос освещён достаточно скудно, поэтому будет сложно.

Вот [эту тему](https://laravel.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?id=2874) посмотрите также, задача похожая, можно будет подсмотреть некоторую конкретику.

Answer (score 0):

нагрузка будет ужасная, Вам проще объединить 2 базы в 1 базу, добавить суффиксы к таблицам чтобы не путалось, а таблицу user сделать единой для 2 сайтов!